# FPS shown in ffmpeg does not match with total frames/duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

FPS is defined as number of frames per second. But when I try to calculate FPS using total frames / duration, I get slightly different number than the FPS shown in ffmpeg:

For this video http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4
using ffmpeg, we can get its FPS, duration and total frames:

> ffprobe -select_streams v -show_streams ForBiggerFun.mp4 | grep nb_frames

nb_frames=1440

> ffmpeg -i ForBiggerFun.mp4

23.98 fps
Duration: 00:01:00.07

If we calculate duration per frame using nb_frames, we get
fps = nb_frames/Duration = 1440/60.07 = 23.972032628599965, which is different from 23.98

Which value is more reliable? Does the difference means duration of a frame might be different from others (frames are not evenly distributed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both the duration and fps are rounded to two decimal places.

To get a more precise reading, run

```
ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v -show_entries stream=duration_ts,time_base,nb_frames  ForBiggerFun.mp4
```

which will produce

```
[STREAM]
time_base=1/48000
duration_ts=2881920
nb_frames=1440
[/STREAM]
```

Your precise framerate is `nb_frames / (duration_ts / time_base)` = `1440 / (2881920 / 48000)` = `23.9840`. Note however that all streams won't have the same duration. Indeed, the audio stream is 30 milliseconds longer, and a player will extend the duration of the video to match that, so arithmetically, effective frame rate is marginally smaller.

Comment: What will the player display during that extra 30 milliseconds, black screen? Or the player assume video has duration to be max(audio_duration, video_duration) ?
I plan to use current time * FPS to represent frame number of video. This extra time makes the problem become  complicated.

Comment: Most players will extend the final frame till audio ends. If your video is variable frame rate, then `current time * FPS` cannot provide reliable frame index.

Comment: Is `current time * FPS` reliable to calculate frame index for constant frame rate video? Which formula should I use to calculate frame index for variable frame rate video?

Comment: For CFR, it's fine. There's no formula for VFR since frames can last for variable amount of time.